What is the most efficient way to find the area of a circle given three points on the rim
let there be three points in $\mathbb{R}^2$, $(x_1,y_1)$, $(x_2,y_2)$, and $(x_3,y_3)$. I want to find the area of the circle that passes through all three points?
I can find the circle by:
$$
\begin{cases}
    (x_1 - x_c)^2 + (y_1 - y_c)^2 - r^2\\
    (x_2 - x_c)^2 + (y_2 - y_c)^2 - r^2 \\
    (x_3 - x_c)^2 + (y_3 - y_c)^2 - r^2
  \end{cases}
$$
isolate $y_c$ and $x_c$ as a function of the isolated $y_c$:
$$\begin{cases}
(x_2 - x_c)^2 - (x_1 - x_c)^2 + (y_2 - y_c)^2 - (y_1 - y_c)^2 = 0\\
(x_3 - x_c)^2 - (x_1 - x_c)^2 + (y_3 - y_c)^2 - (y_1 - y_c)^2 = 0 
\end{cases}$$
$$\begin{cases}
x_2^2 - 2x_2x_c + x_c^2 - x_1^2 + 2x_1x_c- x_c^2 + (y_2 - y_c)^2 - (y_1 - y_c)^2 = 0\\
x_3^2 - 2x_3x_c + x_c^2 - x_1^2 + 2x_1x_c- x_c^2 + (y_3 - y_c)^2 - (y_1 - y_c)^2 = 0 
\end{cases}$$
$$\begin{cases}
x_c = \frac{(y_1 - y_c)^2 - (y_2 - y_c)^2 - (x_2^2 - x_1^2)}{2(x_1 - x_2)}\\
x_c = \frac{(y_1 - y_c)^2 - (y_3 - y_c)^2 - (x_3^2 - x_1^2)}{2(x_1 - x_3)}
\end{cases}$$
$$ y_c= \frac{(x_3x_1 + y_2^2)(x_1 - x_3) + (x_1x_2 + y_3^2)(x_2 - x_1) + (x_2x_3 + y_1^2)(x_3 - x_2)}{2[(y_1 - y_3)(x_1 - x_2) - (y_1 - y_2)(x_1 - x_3)]} $$
From here, we can calculate $x_c$, $y_c$, and $r^2$. Then, the area of the circle $S$ is given by $S=\pi r^2$.
I am going to implement this in a program and I am mainly aiming for runtime optimization. What would be the fastest way to calculate the area $S$ from the three points?

The circumradius is the length from the center of the circle to the vertex of the triangle. $R = \frac{ a b c }{\sqrt{ ( a + b + c ) ( b + c − a ) ( c + a − b ) ( a + b − c ) }}$, where a,b, and c are lengths of the sides of the triangle (see here).  I leave it to you as an exercise to find the area of the circumcircle once you know the circumradius.  Note that the expression in the denominator (up to a factor of 4) is Heron's formula for the area of the triangle.

I was not familiar with circumradiuses. Thanks. After reading about it, and if I understand correctly, Isn't this simply the radius of the circle I am looking for? That is, isn't the area given simply by $\pi R^2$ where $R$ is the circumradius? If so, where is the exercise? I feel like I am missing something.

That was a joke (the exercise was to use the formula $\pi R^2$ :-)

Other than the Heron/Brahmagupta formula for area of a triangle, we can also  evaluate it using  the determinant form populated by 6  coordinates.

Heron was in 70 AD whereas Brahmagupta was in the 7th century.  @Narasimham

Not quite the Heron's formula, but Heron's formula multiplied by 4 (you're basically using the fact that $abc = 4R\Delta$.

For any two points $A,B$  on the circle the center is located on the line perpendicular to the segment $AB$ and passing through the middle point of $AB.$ For three points $A,B$ and $C$ we determine the two  lines corresponding to $AB$ and $AC$ and the point $O$ of their intersection. These steps require linear equations. Once you got the center $O$ you calculate the square of the radius by determining $OA^2.$ There are no square roots on the way. The only approximation step comes at the very end when you multiply by $\pi.$
Remark Assume the coordinates of all three points are rational numbers. Then all quantities in the procedure are rational numbers, including  the square of the radius. The multiplication by $\pi$ is the only exception. So the exact calculations, by hand, can be performed up to penultimate step.

You can also compute the derivative of a polynomial by using the limit definition of the derivative :-)  But why do that if you have a ready-made formula?

@MikhailKatz There are no square roots in the procedure, unlike in the formula, where there are three of them. In this way it is easier  to implement  this procedure. That's was the aim of the asker.

It would be interesting to compare the computational complexity of the two approaches.  To use the formula, one needs to evaluate three square roots.  To use the midpoint perpendiculars, one needs several more steps involving linear procedures only, including finding slopes.  It is hard for me to tell which would be more efficient.

@MikhailKatz There are more steps, all of them linear, except for the last one,  but no approximation required for calculating square roots.

I don't really understand your point about not needing approximation.  Any calculation implemented on the computer will necessarily involve approximation.  Do you mean to say that your approach will result in an exact formula in terms of the parameters of the original problem (namely coordinates of the points)?

@MikhailKatz: "It is hard for me to tell which would be more efficient." ==== The one involving iterating to evaluate a series would be slower. That's the SQRT method.

@DuceexMachina, that may depend on how a procedure is implemented.  A programmer working for me once told me that roots don't take particularly long because they are well-implemented.

@MikhailKatz: depends. 64-bit precision iterative  vs mpy add? No bet. Plus, I hate recursion and am biased against it.

@DuceexMachina, thanks for your comments.  I am not knowledgeable in this area so I can't really comment.  Ryszard Szwarc's method is certainly preferable in the sense that it gives a formula without radicals.  I wonder how one could reconcile the two approaches.
